# Show [In] and [Out] tags after quitting Mathematica

Tags: evaluation

I cannot find a way to show [in] and [out] tags when evaluating cells after I close the application. Is there a way to keep these shown? I disabled the kernel in global options but cannot transfer those settings to my "notebook" can anyone help?

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the `CellLabelAutoDelete` option to `False`. You can do that in the Option Inspector in the Format menu.